# Operator overloading function is not working

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class Array this class has functions like set values to an array index or get a value of an array index, i wanted to make an overloading operator function to add two Arrays objects and the result is one array which every element is the sum of the same index elements of the other two arrays like:
Array A={1,4,6}, Array B={1,20,3} c=A+B //c={1+1,4+20,6+3}.
the problem is that in the Sum Array object i am getting some random values instead of the sum values ,i think they are some addresses cus my overloading function somehow is not working properly.

```
public:

    Array(int asize)
        :size(asize)
    {

        Arr = new int[size];
    }
Array(const Array &other) {
        size = other.size;
        Arr = new int[other.size];//
        for (int x = 0;x < other.size - 1;x++)
            Arr[x] = other.Arr[x];
    }
 Array operator+(const Array &other) {
        Array t(*this);// creating new array with the values of the left hand Array


        int ssize = (other.size < size) ? other.size : size;//if the right hand array size is 
        for (int x = 0;x < ssize;x++)                            //smaller than the left side(choose the smallest size)     
        {
            t.Arr[x] += other.Arr[x];
        }

        return t;
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] Arr;
    }
    int get(int index) {
        return Arr[index];
    }
    void set(int index, int value) {
        Arr[index] = value;
    }

    int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    Array operator+(const  Array  &rhs)  {//I also tried without const and without & sign
        Array H(this->getSize());
        for (int i = 0;i < this->getSize();i++)
        {
            H.Arr[i] = rhs.get(i)+this->get(i);//or rhs.Arr[i]+this->Arr[i];
            }
        return H;
    }


private:
    int size;
    int *Arr;


     };
```

and this is my main function:

```
std::cout << "\n enter the size of the Array" << std::endl;
    int Size1;
    std::cin >> Size1;
    Array A1(Size1);
    std::cout << "insert the elements starting of the first element of the Array" << std::endl;
    int E1;
    for (int i = 0;i < Size1;i++) {
        std::cout << "Element number" << i + 1 << " is: " << std::endl;

        std::cin >> E1;
        A1.set(i, E1);

    }


    std::cout << "\nenter the size of the Array 2" << std::endl;
    int Size2;
    std::cin >> Size2;
    Array A2(Size2);
    std::cout << "insert the elements starting of the first element of the Array" << std::endl;
    int E2;
    for (int i = 0;i < Size2;i++) {
        std::cout << "Element number" << i + 1 << " is: " << std::endl;

        std::cin >> E2;
        A2.set(i, E2);

    }

    Array sum(2);// I am currently trying with only 2 elements Arrays just to check if its working
    sum = A1 + A2;
    for (int i = 0;i < Size2;i++) {
        std::cout << sum.get(i) << " , ";
    }
```

Comment: You don't have copy constructor/assignment defined, see e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: I just edited it with a copy constructor but still the same problem I am getting addresses back from the Sum array instead of sum values

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to the copyt constructor, please note

```
 Array sum(2);// I am currently trying with only 2 elements Arrays just to check if its working
    sum = A1 + A2;
```

This mean you need also operator= to be defined for your code to work properly.

BTW if you write:  Array sum(A2 + A2); instead of those two lines, this will work also with no operator=.

Comment: yes you are right that makes sense, I also tried your advise to write sum(A1+A2) it worked partially, I only got the first element as a value but the second element is still an address but its a good start I think haha .